# Cython with `cimport numpy` fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cython

Similar questions have been asked many, many times, but unfortunately I have yet again ran into a problem with using Cython with Numpy. Take this minimal example (which pretty much follows the examples [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html)):

```
# file test.pyx
import numpy as np
#cimport numpy as np

def func():
    print("hello")
```

Which I try to build with:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "g++-7"

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx", include_path = [np.get_include()])
)
```

This example works (`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`), until I un-comment the `cimport ...` line, after which I get the well know error:

> fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory

The path returned by `np.get_include()` does have the `arrayobject.h` header, but in the actual `g++` command that gets executed, the include dir is missing as a `-I/...`:

> g++-7 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c test.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/test.o

Any idea what might cause this problem?

I'm using Python 3.6.1 on Mac OS, everything (Cython, Numpy, ..) installed with `pip3`, and Cython 0.25.2.

Comment: Can you try: `ext_modules = cythonize((Extension("test",
                     sources=["test.pyx"],
                     include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                     ),
                     ))`

Comment: Also, what is the version of cython? `cython3 --version`

Comment: Pierre, that's magic! It works, although I don't know why/how (yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the simple cythonize command, use

```
ext_modules = cythonize((Extension("test", sources=["test.pyx"], include_dirs=[np.get_include()], ), ))
```

The `include_dirs` option is given here to "Extension" instead of using `include_path` with "cythonize".

Answer (score 1):

My workaround:

```
os.environ["C_INCLUDE_PATH"] = np.get_include()
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx")
)
```